# tmux get variable value from shell inside tmux configuration

Tags: bash, configuration, tmux

Is there any way to get value to variable to tmux config via shell.

I write some script, but it can't set to variable like bash script.

```
enName=$(ip addr show | awk '/inet.*brd/{print $NF}' | grep -o -P '^e.*')
wlName=$(ip addr show | awk '/inet.*brd/{print $NF}' | grep -o -P '^w.*')
[[ ! -z $wlName ]] && interface=$wlName || interface=$enName
ip=$(ifconfig $interface | grep 'inet ' | awk '{print $2}')
net_device_ip="$interface $ip"
```

--edit--

> the actually I want is maintain the variable net_device_ip in tmux configuration file. The bash script is running in tmux way in it's configuration if it is possible.

what I wanna set just like:
`set -g status-left " #[fg=colour160]#S #{net_device_ip}"`

How to set variable and run shell via use tmux command run-shell & set-environment

Thanks

(tmux version : 3.0a)

Comment: As an aside, those are [useless `grep`s.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score -1):

You very nearly have it. You just need a `$` instead of a `#` on your variable evaluation.

I tested this out with just a dummy variable in my `.tmux.conf`.

I'm a bit unclear on if you are attempting to maintain your script and your tmux conf file as two different pieces, but you will need to either run the script from or write the script into your `.tmux.conf` file so that `net_device_ip` is defined in the scope there.

So a complete solution would be to add this to the end of your `.tmux.conf` file:

```
enName=$(ip addr show | awk '/inet.*brd/{print $NF}' | grep -o -P '^e.*')
wlName=$(ip addr show | awk '/inet.*brd/{print $NF}' | grep -o -P '^w.*')
[[ ! -z $wlName ]] && interface=$wlName || interface=$enName
ip=$(ifconfig $interface | grep 'inet ' | awk '{print $2}')
net_device_ip="$interface $ip"

set -g status-left " #[fg=colour160]#S ${net_device_ip}"
```

Comment: do u have the same tmux error in `unknown command: addr` in script `enName=$(ip addr show | awk '/inet.*brd/{print $NF}' | grep -o -P '^e.*')` write in .tmux.conf ?

Comment: Ah you got me there. `.tmux.conf` is sourced, not executed when a new tmux session is started. So I'm incorrect. I will edit my answer tomorrow. A more complete solution would be to put it in a script and use something like ShawnW's answer here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80473/how-do-i-run-a-shell-command-from-tmux-conf ), then alias tmux to the script.

Comment: Finally, I write some script. And invoke the value via bash use `#(the script path)` in .tmux.conf